# How To Replace Dot With Null or Empty Row Using Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe `data` that looks this this:

```
    age
0   .
1   1.2
2   9
3   .
```

I want to convert all the rows that have `.` to an empty value (or `np.nan`).
My desired output would be:

```
    age
0   
1   1.2
2   9
3
```

I tried two different regular expressions which both didn't work:

```
data['age'] = data['age'].str.replace(r'^(.)$', '')
data['age'] = data['age'].str.replace(r'\D', '')
```

Both of the results:

```
    age
0   
1   NaN
2   NaN
3
```

Comment: What is meant by empty ? This `^[^\d]*(?:\.[^\d]*)+$` ? Which would only partially validate Not a Number.

Comment: `str.replace(r'^\.$', '')`. A literal dot must be escaped in a regex.

Comment: In its simplest form, if it doesn't match this `^(?:\s*\d+\s*(?:\s*\.\s*\d*)?|\s*\.\s*\d+\s*)$` it's not a number.